# Is class dict(dict) undesirable if I only want to overwrite __str__

Tags: python

Is this approach undesirable? I want all proceeding dicts to behave this way.

```
import json

class dict(dict):
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return json.dumps(self, indent=4)
```

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "all dicts"?  I believe this code will only affect dicts within the same module as your class redefinition.

Comment: And I believe it will only affect objects that are created by calling `dict()`.  It will not affect dict literals such as `{'foo': 'bar'}` or even `{}`

Comment: @JohnGordon - My mistake. I meant all "future" dicts ~ every dict instance coming after this overwrite.

Comment: Does your application consist of only this one module?

Comment: @JohnGordon - That's correct, and you just answered my question. You just said exactly why this breaks. This is unfortunately not a solution.

Comment: @JohnGordon - if you wrapped your comments up into an answer I would accept it. Easy 25 points if you want them.